# Is there any alternative to $ssh->print() and $ssh->waitfor() , ssh is a new Net::Telnet?

Tags: perl, ssh, telnet

I'm trying to run an ssh command through perl script using `$ssh->print('cmd')`, and match some prompt using `$ssh->waitfor(-match => regex )`. In some cases, the waitfor couldn't catch the prompt. is there any alternative to ssh print()/waitfor() ?

https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet

Comment: Yes, [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH).

Answer (score 0):

$ssh->getline() and match manually

Comment: after we use ``` $ssh->print(cmd) ``` ? will getline() captures the prompt quickly compared to waitfor() ? what if the output is multiple lines?

Comment: you can use getline() in a loop.

Comment: Could you elaborate?